# In python convert day of year to month and fortnight

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I want to convert day (say 88) and year (say 2004) into its constituent month and nearest number out of 2 possibilities:

If the day of month ranges from 1 to 14, then return 1, else return 15

I am doing this:

```
datetime.datetime(year, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(days - 1)
```

However, this is only part of the way to the soln. The end result for day 88 and year 2004 should be:

March 15 (Month is March and closest day is 15th march).

-- EDIT: Changed question to reflect that I mean day of year and not julian day

Comment: hang on, arent julian days absolute from sometime way back? what does julian day 88 of year 2004 mean? 2004 julian year?

Comment: good catch @pvg, Changed question to reflect that I mean day of year and not julian day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the replace method:

```
In [11]: d
Out[11]: datetime.datetime(2004, 3, 28, 0, 0)

In [12]: d.replace(day=1 if d.day < 15 else 15)
Out[12]: datetime.datetime(2004, 3, 15, 0, 0)

In [13]: t = pd.Timestamp(d)

In [14]: t.replace(day=1 if t.day < 15 else 15)
Out[14]: Timestamp('2004-03-15 00:00:00')
```

The reason this returns a new datetime rather than updating is because datetime objects are immutable (they are can't be updated).

Note: there's a [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for that day of the month:

```
In [21]: datetime.datetime.strptime("2004+88", "%Y+%j")
Out[21]: datetime.datetime(2004, 3, 28, 0, 0)

In [22]: pd.to_datetime("2004+88", format="%Y+%j")
Out[22]: Timestamp('2004-03-28 00:00:00')
```

Comment: it is important to note (I see that It confuses people new to Python) that `datetime` is immutable object and therefore `.replace()` can't modify it inplace -- it returns a new datetime object instead.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian added comment to be more specific about that. IMO Immutability is a little surprising (most python objects are mutable)... I guess datetimes are complicated enough without every method potentially mutating them!

Comment: it is not python-specific: having a mutable date/time type is a bad design. It is not a coincidence that basic types such as `str`, `int`, `float` are immutable in Python and many other languages (notable exception is C/C++ where strings are mutable by default).

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
year = 2015
day = 88
d = dt.datetime(year, 1, 1) + dt.timedelta(88 - 1)

>>> d.month, 1 if d.day < 15 else 15
(3, 15)
```

It would be easy to convert the tuple pair into something useful depending on your requirements.

For example

```
dt.datetime(year, d.month, 1 if d.day < 15 else 15).strftime('%Y-%b-%d')
'2015-Mar-15'
```

However, you have not specified the type of data you are expecting (datetime.date, pd.Timestamp, string, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

How about something like..

```
tmp_date = datetime.datetime(year, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(days - 1)
rday = 1 if tmp_date.day < 15 else 15
result = datetime.datetime(tmp_date.year, tmp_date.month, rday)
```